# Can't setup product catalog and product feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Following the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-catalog) i've tried to create a product catalog and a product feed so i can dynamically update ads with this feed, but couldn't manage to do so ,even though i followed those docs like the bible.

First i created a bussiness manager account,then an apps and then a product catalog.After that i simply added this piece of code in my script:

```
require_once (ABSPATH.'vendor/autoload.php');

use FacebookAds\Object\ProductCatalog;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\ProductCatalogFields;

use FacebookAds\Object\ProductFeed;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\ProductFeedFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\ProductFeedScheduleFields;

$bussiness_id = 241842522939685;

$product_catalog_id = 953601841441659;


$product_catalog = new ProductCatalog(null, $bussiness_id);

$product_catalog->setData(array(
    ProductCatalogFields::NAME => "Test",
));

$product_catalog->create();


$product_feed = new ProductFeed(null, $product_catalog_id);

$product_feed->setData(array(
    ProductFeedFields::NAME => 'Test Feed',
    ProductFeedFields::SCHEDULE => array(
        ProductFeedScheduleFields::INTERVAL => 'DAILY',
        ProductFeedScheduleFields::URL =>'http://www.example.com/sample_feed.tsv',
        ProductFeedScheduleFields::HOUR => 22,
    ),
));

$product_feed->create();
```

Which gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'An Api instance must be provided as argument or set as instance in the \FacebookAds\Api' in C:\wamp\www\site\vendor\facebook\php-ads-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject.php:95 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\site\vendor\facebook\php-ads-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject.php(59): FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject::assureApi(NULL) #1 C:\wamp\www\site\cs-modules\feeds\site\facebook.php(17): FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject->__construct(NULL, 2.4184252293969E+014) #2 C:\wamp\www\site\index.php(884): include('C:\wamp\www\sit...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\site\vendor\facebook\php-ads-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject.php on line 95

I'll give it a shot and say that the first parameter(which now is null as the doc specified), should be a value pointing to the access level of the api but i can't find any docs about what that value should be,where i get it from and so on.Can anyone guide me through this mess,please?

Comment: Did you create your first catalog through business manager?

Comment: @CBroe, yes sir

Comment: Sorry, don‘t know what this is then. You can try and file a documentation bug, and ask them if there’s anything more needed to get the example running. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late, but if someone needs an answer. You have to initialize Api first: `FacebookAds\Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);`